# In Javascript, can you make a function return the value of evaluating other function based on conditionals?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

*I tried asking the question in a simplified form and ended up being impossible to understand. I rewrote the question with the real case to make it meaningful.*

I am writing a Google Apps Script in which I am using a self-made library to handle common tasks.

Can I call a helper function from another function (in this case, the doGet() function which is called as a standard http request when you publish the app), and evaluate its return value in the outer scope?

To be clear, I want doGet(e) to return the result of `Security.permissionGateway` (`TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403)`) if the "testgroup" doesn't have the proper permissions. Otherwise, I want it to render "HI THERE". And this is because what the doGet(e) function returns is what is rendered in the browser.

`.throwErrorPage()` function returns this:

```
return html.evaluate()
  .setTitle(code)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Maybe I am missing something very basic, but I am kinda lost here :\

function A:

```
function doGet(e) {

  TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");

}
```

function B:

```
Security.permissionGateway = function(group) {
  if (!Security.activeUserBelongsToGroup(group)) {
    return TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403);
  }
}
```

Sorry if it is not so clear, but what I am really trying to explain is, how can I make THIS:

```
function doGet(e) {

  TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");

}
```

Behave like THIS:

```
function doGet(e) {

  if (!Security.activeUserBelongsToGroup(group)) {
    return TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403);
  }

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");

}
```

I am very sorry about my other post and putting up a horrible example.

Comment: Did it give you an error? "Can this work" questions are best answered by running the code.

Comment: No it doesn't. If I run the code, permissionGateway gets executed and returns a string, but it is not passed to doGet.

Comment: Note this isnt specific about apps script. Its a basic question about programming functions Thus i lowered its score

Comment: @ZigMandel I only tagged it as javascript. A mod edited the tags for me and added google-apps-scripts. Thanks fro the downvote anyway :)

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but this is too specific to your case and unlikely to help anyone else. Thus I cant see why someone upvoted it unless it was coordinated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are calling the `permissionGateway` function, but you never evaluate the result of it. This should work:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var res = TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");
    if (res) {
        return res;
    }
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");
}
```

or in slightly shorter:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var res = TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");
    return res || HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");
}
```

or even shorter:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup") || HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");
}
```

(it is assumed that `throwErrorPage` always returns a truthy value)

Comment: This is the closest to the behavior I want to achieve. 

However, I would like to know if there's any way of doing something like `return TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");` but avoiding it if the result from the function is false or null.

Your design is working, but I'd prefer a DRYier way of doing it, so In case I want to change some aspect of the gateway function I just have to do it in the library.

Comment: @JavierK since `false` and `null` are both falsy, this method will still work and in both cases the result of `createHtmlOutput` will be returned. If you need a more detailed check, just implement it in the `if` clause: `if (res !== null && res !== false && res !== undefined) {...}`. And there is not really a DRYier way of doing this. Your gateway function produces some result and depending on that result you perform this or that action. If you change the gateway function in a way that it produced different results, you (probably) also need to change the function that handles those results.

Answer (score 0):

Like you noted in your code, you need an explicit return statement around the Security call.

Code is behavior, there is no way to just call a method & expect it to exit out early without explicitly coding it to do just that.

In the example code the call to Security.permissionGateway returns undefined if no error, otherwise whatever "TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403)" generates (hopefully not undefined). If that is the case then the code below should do what you want:

```
var handled = TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");
if(handled === undefined){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");
}
return handled;
```

Comment: That is precisely what I would like to know. Can a inner function make the outer function return an inner value?

Comment: No, you cannot. The example I provided is the closest way you can match what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to make your function A work as is, but if you want to keep your error throwing contained in the permissionGateway method, you could do something like this:

```
Security.permissionGateway = function(group) {
  if (!Security.activeUserBelongsToGroup(group)) {
    return TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var permissionError = TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");

  return permissionError || HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
function doGet() {
  var error =  Library.isValid(false)
  return error || HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("WEB APP RAN");
}
```

In library

```
function isValid(boolToken){
  if(!boolToken){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("THIS IS AN ERROR!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the solution after approaching it with a different perspective. Instead of trying to make the inner function force the outer to return the former value, I simply pass a 2nd variable to the inner value containing a function to be executed if the permissions are right.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return TARS.Security.permissionMiddleware(TARS.TARS_Constants.GROUPS.MARKETING, chainedFunction);
}

var chainedFunction = function() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi");
}
```

And for the permissions "middleware":

```
Security.permissionMiddleware = function(group, chainedFunction) {
  if (!Security.activeUserBelongsToGroup(group)) {
    return TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403);
  }

  return chainedFunction();
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: @basilikum What do you think of this? Thank you! :)